# Implement functions without using tail

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, tail

I created a program to invert the non-vowels sequences of a word, represented by a simple linked list, but I should've done so without using Tail- pointer to the last node.

I used this feature in `createList`, `pop` (used to pop list and return letter char of each node), `push_back`  and `push_front` (both used to invert non-vowel sequences. For example, `push_front` puts a node in front of the list that contains the sequence analyzed: node-> a-> b-> c. `push_back`, in the same way, makes the sequence a-> b-> c be a-> b-> c-> node).

```
LIST *createList(void){
    LIST *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if(list){
        list->first = list->tail = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}

char pop(LIST *list){
    char ch = list->first->letter;

    list->first = list->first->next;
    if(list->first == NULL)
        list->tail = NULL;
    return ch;
}

void push_back(LIST *list, char ch){
    NODE *node = createNode(ch);
    if(list->first)
        list->tail = list->tail->next = node;
    else
        list->tail = list->first = node;
}

void push_front(LIST *list, char ch){
    NODE *node = createNode(ch);
    if(list->first){
        node->next = list->first;
        list->first = node;
    } else {
        list->tail = list->first = node;
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how I can replace tail pointer, which is in typedef, by some local variable or another implementation of the functions above.

Comment: You can decide the last element by tracing the list from the beginning instead of the `tail` pointer, but it is inefficient as the list gets longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only really need to change push_back since it pushes to the end of the list

```
void push_back(LIST *list, char ch){
    NODE *node = createNode(ch);
    NODE *tmp = list->first;

    if (tmp)
      while(tmp)
      {
         if (tmp->next == NULL)
         { 
            tmp->next = node;
            tmp = tmp->next;
         }
         tmp = tmp->next;         
      }
    else
      list->first = node;
}
```

You can find the complete implementation here https://repl.it/KiBB/6